# Why use ASP.NET Core modelbinding attributes?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

For what reason should we apply these attributes in ASP.NET Core model binding?

What are the consequences of not using them?

Isn't the model binding engine able to search through the incoming request and map them to Controller action method parameters without these attributes:

- `[FromQuery]` - Gets values from the query string.
- `[FromRoute]` - Gets values from route data.
- `[FromForm]` - Gets values from posted form fields.
- `[FromBody]` - Gets values from the request body.
- `[FromHeader]` - Gets values from HTTP headers.

See this Controller action method examples:

```
public ActionResult<Pet> Create([FromBody] Pet pet)

public ActionResult<List<Pet>> Search([FromRoute] string breed, [FromQuery] string color, [FromQuery] int age)
```

We can also apply the attributes to the model class:

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Controller action method examples without attributes:

```
public ActionResult<Pet> Create(Pet pet)

public ActionResult<List<Pet>> Search(string breed, string color, int age)
```

Comment: Security is probably a reason for it. When using these attributes you are explicitly stating from which source you are expecting the values. So that we can prohibit Parameter Tampering.

Comment: You can use them if you want non-default binding sources or names.

Comment: Model binding allows for binding complex types so you can bind `Pet` instead of individual values like `breed`. It also allows for binding nested complex types, arrays, dictionaries, collections, etc.

Comment: You could check the [Sources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources) description, By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs from the following sources in an HTTP request: Form fields, The request body (For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute), Route data, Query string parameters, Uploaded files. For each target parameter or property, the sources are scanned in the order indicated in the preceding list. If the default source is not correct, we can use one of the attributes to specify the source.

Comment: How to make binding from all available sources by default without using attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources) description:

*By default, model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs from the following sources in an HTTP request:*

1. *Form fields*
2. *The request body (For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute.)*
3. *Route data*
4. *Query string parameters*
5. *Uploaded files*

*For each target parameter or property, the sources are scanned in the order indicated in the preceding list. If the default source is not correct, we can use one of the following attributes to specify the source:*

- *[FromQuery] - Gets values from the query string.*
- *[FromRoute] - Gets values from route data.*
- *[FromForm] - Gets values from posted form fields.*
- *[FromBody] - Gets values from the request body.*
- *[FromHeader] - Gets values from HTTP headers.*

For example:

When using the following method, it will get the pet data from the form fields:

```
public ActionResult<Pet> Create(Pet pet)
```

If using the following method, it will get the parameter from the default source. We can pass the parameter via the Form or Query string.

```
public ActionResult<List<Pet>> Search(string breed, string color, int age)
```

If adding attribute to above method, like this:

```
public ActionResult<List<Pet>> Search([FromQuery]string breed, [FromQuery]string color, [FromQuery]int age)
```

You could only pass the parameter via the Query string. In this scenario, if you pass the parameters via Form, the parameters in the action method will be `Null`.

So, by using these attributes we could specify the model binding source, without to scan the default source list.